# SQL Server query count of the minimum value for distinct names in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have the following result from a query and i want to make a subquery that counts the number of the minimum value in each name.

For example:

```
Marcus 25  
Marcus 27  
Marcus 25  
Jonathan 36  
Jonathan 36  
Jonathan 36  
Jonathan 38
```

And the result should be :

```
Marcus 25 2
Jonathan 36 3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Should `Marcus 3` be considered bigger or smaller than `Marcus 27`?

Comment: What do you mean by Marcus 3?

Comment: If you had such a value, would it be considered bigger or smaller then the `Marcus 27` you already have? doesn't matter for this question since you've accepted Gordon's answer but it's something to think about - strings have different sorting rules then numbers.

Comment: @ZoharPeled they are two different columns. Marcus is the name. 27 is the value.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks, it makes sense now. I should probably get some more sleep....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.name, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by name order by val) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

Oh, the OP also wants the value:

```
select t.*
from (select t.name, t.val, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by val) as seqnum
      from t
      group by t.name, t.val
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```